# Possible in Linux for root to take ownership of a running process without restarting it?

Tags: linux, process, administrator, root, chown

There is a process running under my personal login id that I want to run under root instead.  This is only temporary for troubleshooting a problem with it.  My login id has sudo privilege but is not root.

Stopping this process results in it automatically and immediately restarting, so it's difficult to manually run it under root before it restarts.

Is there some way to make root take ownership of a running process, or otherwise restart a process under root while bypassing its normal restart under its default owner id?

Comment: You would need to determine what is automatically restarting it and configure that to use the user you wish to use

Comment: (1) The question (especially the title) smells like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). The body of the post reveals there is an actual underlying problem, without details though. (2) "while bypassing its normal restart" – I think you need to know how the "normal restart" happens, then you can modify it.

Comment: More details might be fruitful. Like what sort of problem?  What sort of process?  Is this code available?  How are you running it now?